# tickVisible missing in Material Design Slider

Tags: android, slider, material-design

I am implementing `Material Design Slider` in my project, but I am facing one issue. I have seen `tickVisible` property is there in the [Material Slider documentation](https://material.io/components/sliders)(Screenshot attached). But, When I am using it in project it throws an error `tickVisible` not found as follows:

```
error: attribute tickVisible (aka com.demoapp:tickVisible) not found.
```

Xml Code:

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
     android:id="@+id/sliderVolume"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="10dp"
     app:haloColor="@color/app_red"
     app:thumbColor="@color/app_red"
     app:trackColorActive="#696969"
     app:trackColorInactive="@color/app_black"
     app:tickVisible="false" />
```

Any idea why it is happening? Thank in advance.

[image]

Comment: which version of material components are you using?

Comment: version 1.2.1 @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: I just checked tickVisible is introduced in version 1.3.0-alpha03. So, I updated to version 1.3.0(stable). but tick is still visible @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: I set tickVisible to false but it still showing the tick on the top of Slider's thumb on sliding. Any thoughts?